# Address parsing: recognize pattern, then cut and paste value into correct position in same column

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R and still getting the hang of it, and right now I am trying to tidy some data.  One of the most common things I see in my field is addresses with messy data.  Sometimes I will see for example suite 206 123 main street.  The suite 206 is obviously in the wrong position. The last three test objects have errors and i'm beyond frustrated at this point.  Went for a walk and now ready to tackle problem again by reaching out for help.

I have tried removing the suite 206 from the address variable, but have not been successful.

I have tried the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- readxl::read_excel("path")

df1 <- df %>% select(Address,`Desired Result`)

address_list <- df1 %>% mutate(list(`Address`))

names(address_list) = c('Address','Desired Address','Address List')

splice_list <- address_list[-(2:3)]

new <- (splice_list[c(1)]) 

test <- sub("suite", "", new)
names(test) = c("Address", "New Address")
```

I have tried other ways such as using test <- "(`[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}`)" to detect patterns, and replace patterns.  I also pondered of an easier way to do this such as recognize the pattern, then splice the recognized pattern (value), then insert it into a new column then finally concatenate.  Or a function that can check each row in the data-set and replace and move to the correct position based off the pattern would be nice.

Screenshot of Address column with desired result:

[image: Screenshot of Address column with desired result]

Comment: Address parsing is pretty difficult to get consistently right. I think your suggestion to split and recombine makes the most sense. In dealing with similar problems, I've typically removed nearly all punctuation and replaced with spaces, then split each address into multiple rows, labelled each piece using some rules, then tried to piece it back together in the order I want. See tools like `str_extract` and `str_split` and even the *tidyr* `separate_rows` which might be helpful - https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html

Answer (score 0):

[Solution to Address Parsing Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT4PD.png)

i'm sure this could be done in fewer lines.